Is there a better way to update all relation rows with `ForegnKey` relation in `Django ORM`
I have two models, one like this:
class PhysicalSensor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class Sensor(models.Model):
    physical_sensor = models.ForeignKey(PhysicalSensor, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True, blank=True)

So, when I want to add a PhisycalSensor record, I want to set the Sensor records to that.
Right now I handle this in my Serializer class:

class PhysicalSensorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    sensors = SensorSerialiazer(required=False, many=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ("__all__")
        model = PhysicalSensor

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sensors = validated_data.pop("sensors")
        ph_sensor = super().create(validated_data)

        for sensor in sensors:
            s = Sensor.objects.get(sensor["id"])
            s.physical_sensor = ph_sensor
            s.save()

and for edit of PhysicalSensor, I use the same thing in .update() method of my Serializer.
Is there any batter way of doing this or a best practice for this ?

The best way is to use queryset.update method:
 def create(self, validated_data):
    sensors = validated_data.pop("sensors")
    ph_sensor = super().create(validated_data)

    ids = (sensor["id"] for sensor in sensors)
    Sensor.objects.filter(pk__in = ids).update(physical_sensor=ph_sensor)

more here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#update

If I understand this the right way, the filter() method will perform just one query to database, is that right? because my code will perform a query per Sensor.

Exactly. One change query for all Sensors.

Thanks, that is a great optimize for my code.

@parsariyahi if this does it for you, mark this as complete.
